# What are these screws called?

Tags: screws, woodworking

First is this black screw that has fine thread which goes to the head. There is a corresponding part that the screw enters which is on the left. This part was firmly stuck inside chip wood of desk but it broke out with a loud bang one day by accident. The black screw goes into this yellow part which is fixed into wood and not screwed directly into the wood.

[image]

Next is this other screw, it has coarse thread. The thread does not go all the way to its head and the screw is really long.

[image]

I need to buy more of these three but don't know how to describe these to the hardware shop.

Comment: Be best to take them to the store for the right size.  Top one is a type of machine bolt, the bottom looks like a lag screw.  Both look like made for furniture, instead of general use.  The hole that the nut/anchor was in, is probably ruined now.  A picture of the hole might give someone an idea on how to fix.

Comment: don't know the exact technical term for those, but take them to a local hardware store,  (not a big box).  The people there can find you the screws that match or suggest where to get them.

Comment: Filling the hole with epoxy and drilling a new hole for the threaded insert is one way to go. Another option is to use epoxy to glue in a piece of dowel and use a regular wood screw - unfortunately, this puts the threads into end grain wood and it doesn't hold as well. Significantly stronger than a screw into MDF/particle board, but not was well as cross-grain or into a threaded insert.

Comment: How can I find the thread of a screw myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The top picture shows a fine-thread screw with a [particle board threaded insert](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=threaded%20inserts%20for%20particle%20board&crid=1ABHYEMD40DV8&sprefix=threaded%20insert%20for%20partic%2Caps%2C136&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-doa-p_1_26). There's nothing special about this combination of fasteners other than they have to have the same threads to work together.

The bottom screw is a "[Confirmat screw](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MTSCQ26)" and made for attaching particle board or MDF panels. There are other types of screws made for these materials so you're probably not confined to using these specifically.

You can find these screws from a variety of suppliers and the included links are just examples--not endorsements or recommendations of any kind. You'll likely find better quality fasteners from a different supplier.

If you're trying to match existing holes in furniture (or similar) you may find that the screw holes are stripped out anyways and will need to be repaired. Usually these kind of things don't hold up well to being disassembled/reassembled too many times or being moved around too much. Depending on the application, you may need to drill out the existing screw holes and glue dowels into them to give new screws something to "bite" into. (That would likely be the topic of another question.)

Comment: Yes, I have realized that using dowel is the only way to save this desk. I got the desk during Covid for WFH. It was a used desk.